# Can an empty index.php truly hide its folder?

Tags: php, security, directory, server-side

Say I have an `/images` folder in my website, which I don't want to be browsed by visitors. I usually prevent it by creating an empty `./images/index.php` file. Is it 100% safe?

I mean, if the user knows the filename, they can type `website.com/images/image.jpg`, that's OK, but they cannot see the contents of the folder, right?

Comment: or you can disable directory listing in your server configuration; if you have access to it, that is.

Comment: @itachi yes, but I'm wondering if php, by itself, can handle it. Can it?
[at] roninblade, I'm on a host, so I don't think I can change server settings, I only can upload an .htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Method One**

Put the .htaccess file in the desired folder. Edit this file and put

```
deny from all
```

This way it will solve all your problem of direct access and will not have to put additional index file in the folder.

**Method two**

If you want to go with putting index file or **do not** want any file to be accessed directly, then put

```
<?php
if(!defined('Variable')) {
die('No direct access');
}
?>
```

In the file you dont want to be accessed and put

```
<?php
define('Variable', TRUE);
?>
```

in the index.php.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Igniting Minds ! putting an .htaccess to all folders is equally easy as putting index.php's , but what I'm really trying to learn is, is there any way to get around an empty index file? So do I *have to* use .htaccess to hide the folder?

and for your second method, shouldn't the if statement be if(defined('Variable'))?

Comment: You will prevent the default webserver listing with empty index.php file, but you will not prevent people to brute force scan the folder for filenames.

Comment: First defining the constant in index.php or any file that you want that user can access using- define('variable', TRUE); and the files you dont want to let accessed, check if the "Variable" is defined or not using if(!defined('Variable')) condition. 

Putting an empty index file in a folder will not stop user accessing other files inside that folder. Giving the url as /images/ will surely return nothing if you put the empty index.php file but if user give a url as /images/img.png then it will open that image and index.php will not be able to stop it. So better use method one. It is safe..

Comment: Oh yes I didn't thought of brute force :) Ok, thanks for all answers. I'm choosing this one since it helps the most.

Answer (score 1):

you can write this rule in you server configuration,such as nginx.conf

```
location ^~ /images {
 deny all;
 }
```

this means all request for path like www.website.com/images/xxx are forbidden